# C# version support for mono

Tags: c#, mono

As I know mono supports C# 8(and all other previous versions) but mono project's official [page](https://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/languages/csharp/)
says that latest version is C# 7 and it's implementation is even partial so what's happening is mono's website out of sync or I am misinformed about mono's compiler implementations of C#?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C# 8.0 is supported by .NET Core 3.x and .NET Standard 2.1.<sup>[[1]](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/configure-language-version#defaults)</sup> Mono 6.4+ has partial support for the latter in that it apparently can load and run .NET Standard 2.1 code without an issue, but since a library targeting Standard 2.1 can normally only be referenced by other 2.1 libraries or a .NET Core 3+ executable, writing an application for Mono that can actually utilize .NET Standard 2.1 requires you to invoke the C# compiler manually.<sup>[[2]](https://github.com/dotnet/standard/issues/1689)</sup>

My *personal* guess is that since support for .NET Standard 2.1 (and by extension C# 8) is so extremely limited, they didn't bother including it in the official docs.

<sup>1</sup> [C# language versioning - C# Guide | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/configure-language-version#defaults)

<sup>2</sup> [Clarify how to use .NET Standard 2.1 from Mono · Issue #1689 · dotnet/standard · GitHub](https://github.com/dotnet/standard/issues/1689)

---

As a sidenote, their [Compatibility](https://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/compatibility/) page seems to indicate that C# 7 is fully supported. If you'd like a proper answer as to why the two pages differ, I suggest you ask a question on their [Issue tracker](https://github.com/mono/website/issues).